# Searching bluetooth devices

Tags: bluetooth

Im trying to write a java program to search nearby bluetooth devices.. 
Im using Bluecove-glp-2.1.0 and bluecove 2.1.0

Im working on Ubuntu 13.04 LTS

I typend a code to get the local Device name..

```
package bluetoothsearch;
import javax.bluetooth.*;
public class BluetoothSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           LocalDevice ld= null ;
           String name = ld.getBluetoothAddress();
           System.out.print(name);

    }   
}
```

this is my code..

It returns me null. doesn't return me the local Device.

if anyone helps it will be wonderfull.

Comment: You set ld = null, after that you call its method. It looks inconsistent to me

Comment: it shows error. It says id must be initialize.!!